# BBCode parser for PHP

Tags: html, php, parser

I am searching for a BBCode parser for PHP. I tried many but none of them fit exactly what I want. I will take the example of `[quote]` to explain what I need:

All I want to do is to parse:

- `[quote]something[/quote]` → `<blockquote>something</blockquote>`
- **It can take a parameter, the "source" here, which is optional.**

  `[quote="source"]something[/quote]` → `<blockquote><cite>source</cite>something<blockquote>`
- **You can set the nest limit to forbid unlimited nesting like:**

  `[quote]111[quote]222[quote]333[quote]444[quote]555[ETC][/quote][/quote][/quote][/quote][/quote]`

  Set to 3, it will give me:

  `<blockquote>111<blockquote>222<blockquote>333[quote]444[quote]555[ETC][/quote][/quote]</blockquote></blockquote></blockquote>`
- **When the tags are empty, they are not changed in the wanted result but displayed as it is**  (because if someone posts empty tags in my website, the comment will be empty but valid until I set an additional checker for "comments filled with empty tags only"):

  `[quote]something[quote][/quote][/quote]` must become `<blockquote>something[quote][/quote]</blockquote>`

I don't feel like asking too much but, until now, inventors of the wheel failed at giving me something perfectly circular.

Of course, I need the parser to be customizable (I could create my own tags like `[spoiler]` or `[youtube]`), I could also check the parameter and the content (parameter N of `[size=N]` must be between x and y values, `[url]content[/url]` → content must be a valid URL).

**Is there at least one existing customizable BBCode parser that can fit that set of criteria? If that's the case, which one? I am not asking for the BEST plugin, just link me ONE, if that's even possible.**
(In case nothing can be found, I can live without the nest limit.)

Here are my previous attempt with popular parsers and why they failed my test. I posted this report in appendix, in case I missed something. If that's the case, point me the name of the parser and tell me why I am wrong.

- **BBCode PECL extension**:

  - Cannot set a nest limit.
  - Tags removed if content is empty.
  - Moreover, [I had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546697/error-with-a-callback-function-bbcode-pecl-extension) I still didn't solve (maybe because I am bad at OOP), not that matters anymore.
- **PEAR HTML_BBCodeParser2**:

  - Convert your tag attribute in HTML tag attribute only.
    `[quote="source"]something[/quote]` will turn as `<blockquote cite="source">something</blockquote>`
- **[jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/)**:

  - A tag attribute must be true OR false, not true AND false i.e. it can't be an option.